# Extracting the digits of a number, I want to extract the digits of this number using the following program

Tags: c

I want to use this program to extract the digits of a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int a,b,c,d;
  printf("524");
  scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);
  a=d%10;
  b=(d%10)/10;
  c=d/10;
  printf("Centenas:%d\nDecenas:%d\nUnidades:%d\n",a,b,c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b=(d%10)/10;` will be `0` always.  Also, you're never setting `d`.

Comment: You're setting variables (`scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);`) and then overwriting them (`a=d%10;`, etc.).

Comment: [Edit] your question and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @DracoD. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have written so far? Does it not compile? Do you get a specific error message? Does it give you results that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int number;
  scanf("%d", &number);

  int hundreds = (number / 100) % 10;
  int tenths =( number / 10) % 10;
  int units = number % 10;

  printf("Centenas: %d\nDecenas: %d\nUnidades: %d\n", hundreds, tenths, units);
  return 0;
}
```

Example of input and output:

```
456
Centenas: 4
Decenas: 5
Unidades: 6
```

Comment: Thanks , that's what I was looking for :D

Comment: @DracoD. instead of posting "thank you" you should do what is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh I tried , in the moment that I saw ur answer but it appeared me this message:"  Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.", I am truly sorry

Comment: @DracoD. nothing to be sorry about, upvote the answers you think were useful and accept the one __you__ think is best (not necessarily mine BTW). And yes you can accept only after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

since I don't what is `d` in your code can't help with it but to extract the digits of a number:

```
int main()
{
    int num,i=0,r,j;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int digits[100];
    while (num)
    {
        digits[i] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    }

    printf("Centenas:%d\nDecenas:%d\nUnidades:%d\n", digits[i - 1], digits[i - 2], digits[i - 3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot upvote your answer since I just started posting here.

Comment: @DracoD. nothing to be sorry at all.We all are here to become better programmers and learn.In a case you have more than 3 digits or unknown number of digits I recommend using loops.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @hanie , I'll consider using loops in fututre programs ,have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you opened the topic because your program doesn't work.

First, you declared but didn't initialize the variable `d`. In this case, you can't use it, because it contains a value that you don't know (trash value)

Then, you use `scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);`, letting the user to enter the values of these variables, but then you overwrite their value, making the previous function useless.

This could be the program you're searching for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int unidades, decenas, centenas;
    int number;

    printf("%s", "Enter the three digit number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    unidades = number % 10;
    decenas = (number/10) % 10;
    centenas = (number/100) % 10;

    printf("Centenas: %d\nDecenas: %d\nUnidades: %d\n", centenas, decenas, unidades);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot upvote your answer since I just started posting here.